Microsoft.Identity.Client getting Error in C#
Greetings.
I'm experiencing an error after updating the Microsoft.Identity.Client to the lastest version 4.61.1.
The old version (4.56.0) was working perfectly using the same line of codes:

var authBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
.WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)*
 *//.WithRedirectUri("app://gfdhghg-fa19-5t76hg-ghgh-5646767")* this works with the old version (4.56.0) but not on this version 4.61.1 throwing the error "**Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn::wg:oauth:2.0:oob**"


//.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")*  this works with the new version 4.61.1 but the remote server doesnt not recognize it throwing the below error


AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://localhost:56010' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'gfdhghg-fa19-5t76hg-ghgh-5646767'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.
Do you know how to overcome this issue please?
Thank you
I m trying to access Dynamic CRM 365 using the web API (https://myorganization .api.uyty.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/)

Thank you everyone to all for your answers, I downgraded the version of the lib to 4.56.0 which was working initially.

Sorry for coming back to this, but the finally solution was to remove the client ID in the connectionstring and to set redirect id ="http://localhost". This resolved the issue. New connectionstring is string connectionString = $@"Url={url};RedirectUri ={RedirectUri};AuthType=OAuth;LoginPrompt=Auto;RequireNewInstance=True";  Thank you again to all

If you are trying to access dynamics 365 in C#, I suggest using the Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client. Are you trying to access it via Console App, Azure Function, App Service?
If you are using an Azure Resource like Azure Function/App Service, then you can enable system assigned identity. You can then add the function app/App Service to your environment as follows:

Navigate to you admin center at admin.powerapps.com and click on the environment you want to add the user to and then click on S2S Apps "See All" as indicated in the screenshot below

Then click on new app user on the top left and then add an app on the form that pops up on the right hand side.

Then type the name of your function app/app service and it should appear in the list

Add your relevant business unit and security role and save.


Next, in your code (for this example I will use a startup.cs file in my function app) you need to register the service client in the dependency injection container as follows:
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(my_function_namespace.Startup))]
namespace my_function_namespace
{

  public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
  {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {         

        //any other services you want to register


        // Register the ServiceClient in the dependency injection container
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceClient>(serviceProvider =>
        {

            
            var managedIdentity = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var environment = "https://yourorgurl.crm.dynamics.com";
            var client = new ServiceClient(tokenProviderFunction: async u =>
                (
                    await managedIdentity.GetTokenAsync(
                        new TokenRequestContext(new[] { $"{environment}/.default"
                        }))).Token,
                    instanceUrl: new Uri(environment)
                    );

            if (client.IsReady)
                return client;
            else
                throw client.LastException;


            });             

        builder.Services.AddLogging();
       }
    }
}

You can then inject your service as follows and use the SDK to do calls to the API:
public class SomeDataverseService
{
  private readonly ServiceClient _serviceClient;

  public SomeDataverseService(ServiceClient serviceClient)
  {
    _serviceClient = serviceClient;
  }

  public string GetAccountName(string accountId)
  {
    var account = _serviceClient.Retrieve("account", accountId, new ColumnSet("name", "accountId"));
    if (account == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Account not found");
    }

    var accountName = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
    return accountName;
  }
}

Update:
Using without managed identity and just connection string
var connectionstring = @$"AuthType=ClientSecret;url={orgurl};ClientId={clientId};ClientSecret={clientSecret}";
var _serviceClient = new ServiceClient(connectionString);


Thank you so much for your response, actually i m not the admin of the environment.  m accessing the app as client using winform /console app. The admin of the CRM shared with me the below elements : Username/Pwd, ClientID, TenantID, RedirectURI, APIURI. Those are the elements available. let me try your approach. Thank you

you can use the service client without managed identity as well. I have added an updated solution. Also make sure that when registering the new S2S app user your admin needs to use the ClientID (AppID) created via App Registration in Azure. Here's some info on connection strings and the SDK client - https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient
Connection Strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect?view=op-9-1#connection-string-examples

Thank you for response but still getting the same error. for now I have downgraded the version of the library 4.56.0.   the simple code i m trying to execute is below: using Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client;
string ClientId = "oooop-pkkllkj-jhjhjh";
var RedirectUri = "app://oooop-pkkllkj-jhjhjh";
string orgurl = "https://organization.crm.dynamics.com";
string connectionstring = @$"AuthType=OAuth;Username=;Password=;Url={orgurl};AppId={ClientId};RedirectUri={RedirectUri};";
var _serviceClient = new ServiceClient(connectionstring);

Maybe try to keep the AppId and RedirecUri as follows:
AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;
RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Auto;
so your connection string should look like:
AuthType=OAuth;
Username=yourusername;
Password=yourpassword;
Url={orgurl};
AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;
RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;
LoginPrompt=Auto;
this is the same as in the documentation and are considered default values

Thank you so much for the answers for now the one option is to downgrade to the previous version of the lib. I will close the discussion. thank you
